# Installing mysqld on Ubuntu 12 (LTS) non-interactively

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I want to install MySQL server on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS non-interactively.  For most packages, I just use the -y flag, which is described on the apt-get manpage as:

> Automatic yes to prompts; assume "yes" as answer to all prompts and run non-interactively.

But if I try to install mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.40-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) this way, I get a PC-line-art-style dialog box:

> While not mandatory, it is highly recommended that you set a password for the MySQL administrative "root" user.
>
> If this field is left blank, the password will not be changed.

I really don't care about a root password here (it's for a dev VM with private networking).  I really just need it to run non-interactively.  This value is "not mandatory", after all.

What am I missing?  How do I install mysql on Ubuntu non-interactively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below commands to install mysql non-interactively

```
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password your_password'
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password your_password'
sudo apt-get -y install mysql-server
```

You need debconf-utils installed on your system

```
sudo apt-get install debconf-utils
```